# How to show our custom nuget at top while searching from nuget.org?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

When i search my package with keyword like platform name and control name (**asp.net core datagrid**)it shows in 4 or 5th page in nuget.org. th package contain tags like **aspnetcore and datagrid** and download count *42,345*.

can you please help me how to show our package in first 3 pages?

packages shows in which basis while searching in nuget.org?

Please can anyone explain clear usage of tags and how to use tag in nuget package?
What is the usage of hyphen(-) in tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nuget.org search algorithm heavily favors packages with high download count today. The terms "asp.net" "core" and "aspnetcore" are all very common terms so it's a "crowded space" so to speak. Additionally, there are many extremely popular packages with these terms.

If your package has all three of these terms ("asp.net" "core" "datagrid") ideally this package would be preferred over very popular packages with just 1 or 2 of those terms. This is something that could be improved.

Regarding tags and hyphens, today tags are split on hyphens. An easy example is the AWS SDK packages. These have the tag "aws-sdk-v3". If you search for the "v3" tag this will still pull in these packages even though they don't have a distinct "v3" tag:
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22v3%22

Concerning your particular package's discoverability, could you leave a comment on this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/4124

Please provide your package ID and the search queries that you want to work. We can't guarantee search will work exactly how you want for every search query but user input does help us prioritize "problem areas" in our search algorithm.

It sounds like we should consider two things:

1. If a package has ALL search terms, perhaps it should get more of a boost than it does today.
2. How should tags really be tokenized? Is tokenizing on hyphens the right thing?

As with all search relevancy changes, they have to be tested thoroughly before just making a guess about what is right.